# When will app signing/app bundles be enforced for existing apps?

Tags: android, google-play

While new apps must use Google App Signing/app bundles since August 2021, I can't find anything about existing apps and when they will be enforced to use these things, too.

Is there a timeline? When do I have to expect my apps forced to app signing/app bundles?

Answer (score 0):

There is no required action for the existing apps for now, this applies only for new apps. [Read more here](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2021/06/the-future-of-android-app-bundles-is.html)

Comment: Thanks, I know and I have already read this article.My question is: When can I expect app signing/app bundles to be enforced for my existing apps?

Comment: well, no one knows. Could be next year Google always makes new updates, and it's better to make updates now before they ask for it.